# Tomcat WebApp: Error storing image file outside of context root on OpenShift

Tags: tomcat, web-deployment, openshift

My tomcat web application uploads images and saves them outside the context folder for security. I tested the code on my local machine and it works perfectly.

When I hosted the code on OpenShift, I get a null pointer exception on the line highlighted below:

```
public void init() throws ServletException {
    // get name of images directory
    String imagesPath = getServletContext().getInitParameter(
            PARAM_UPLOAD_IMAGE_PATH);

    //get path to context root directory
    String contextRoot = getServletContext().getRealPath("/");



    //remove trailing '/'
    contextRoot = contextRoot.substring(0,contextRoot.length() - 1);//NULL POINTER EXCEPTON

    //get path of directory outside root, where images will be saved.
    String outsideRoot = contextRoot.substring(0, contextRoot.lastIndexOf("/"));

    uploadPath = outsideRoot + File.separator + imagesPath;
}
```

I don't understand what the problem is because the code works fine on my machine. Do hosting sites not allow you to save files outside the context root? Is there a way around this? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only locations you actually have write permissions to on OpenShift are ~/app-root/data and /tmp.

App-root/data has an environment variable you should use in your code $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR. Please change your code to write to this directory.

Comment: Thanks, so I can just say `File file = new File("$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/MyApp/image.jpg")` and I'll be good to go?